# How to show an actitivity only when an app widget is first created?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-appwidget

My app widget needs to be configured when it first added to the home screen. I want to open a configuration view right after the user adds the widget.

`AppWidgetProvider` has no `onCreated` event, so I'm showing the confugration activity on the `onUpdate` event, and store a boolean value in `SharedConfiguration` that marks that the configuration has already been shown. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the AppWidgetProvider XML file there is an attribute called `android:configure`

You can use this to point to an Activity to launch when the app is dropped onto the home screen. ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure="com.bandsintown.WidgetSettingsActivity"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:minResizeWidth="180dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="110dp"
    android:resizeMode="vertical|horizontal"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="10000" />
```

In your chosen configuration activity, the user can make whatever choice they want. You'll need to grab and store the widget's id. In the `onCreate` method, get the id like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null)
    mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

When they've made their selection, use this to send a message back to your home screen widget that it is ready to be displayed:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

finish();
```

That'll get what you're after.

Comment: Thank you! More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it to the onEnabled function. onEnabled will be called when the app widget added to the screen

> onEnabled(Context) This is called when an instance the App Widget is
>   created for the first time. For example, if the user adds two
>   instances of your App Widget, this is only called the first time. If
>   you need to open a new database or perform other setup that only needs
>   to occur once for all App Widget instances, then this is a good place
>   to do it.

for an example

```
 @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {

    Log.i("INDEX", "WIDGET Enabled");

    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context); 
    RemoteViews defaultViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_restart); 
    Intent idefault = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    idefault.putExtra("widget", "1");
    PendingIntent defaultpendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, idefault, 0);
    defaultViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.headWidget, defaultpendingIntent);
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), Widget.class.getName()); 
    mgr.updateAppWidget(comp, defaultViews); 
    }
```

this will be calle on the first time to set the appearance of the widget when the widget created for the first time

if you have any question feel free to ask me in the comment :)

Comment: As far as I understand, onEnabled is invoked only when the first instance of the widget is added to the home screen. However, I allow the user to add multiple app widgets of the same type, and each needs its own configuration. So if I understand the documentation correctly, onEnabled will only get called for the first widget.

Comment: ah I'm sorry,I think I misunderstand your question, for now I don't have any simpler idea than using sharedpreference,but may I ask,what'll be the difference between your first widget and the others?

Comment: Each widget displays different data. To be more specific, each widget displays bus times for a bus stop. When a new widget is created, I let the user choose the bus stop.